# robovm/libgdx app keeps iOS device active/from locking

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

The iOS version of my libGDX game keeps the phone from locking/dimming/going to sleep. I've set the IOSApplicationConfiguration.preventScreenDimming to false, but this does not help.
Is there any other setting/config I am missing?

full config:

```
IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
config.allowIpod = true;
config.orientationPortrait = true;
config.orientationLandscape = false;
config.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;
config.useAccelerometer = false;
config.useCompass = false;
config.preventScreenDimming = false;
```

Comment: If the phone is plugged in, it won't dim regardless of this setting.

Comment: This also happens when it is not plugged in.